# Does adobe distribute acrobat reader for Linux platforms?

Tags: adobe-flash, gimp, pinta, adobe-acrobat

First things first - If I got it right, the Linux folks might like adobe alternatives like GIMP (instead of Photoshop) etc to work with images/pdf/videos on Linux. So they might never miss adobe products on Linux.

But what brings me to this question is - i found a article  which describes on: [How to Install Adobe Acrobat Reader on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)

I was surprised, because as per my understanding, none of adobe products are available for linux platforms (correct me if I am wrong ).  Then I though Acrobat Reader might be an exception and checked on adobe site. My finding is as captured on the screenshot. --> No, there is no Linux Version of acrobat reader on adobe site.

[image]

1. I want to understand how ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb exists when adobe does not show it on their website (ok even unix version is not listed on there website).
2. Like Acrobat Reader, are there any other products like Flash etc that can obtained through FTP.

Comment: Why is gimp relevant here? Acrobat Reader is just a pdf viewer, the equivalent would be tools like `evince` and `okular`, not `gimp`.

Comment: @terdon, i actually meant `gimp` vs `photoshop`

Comment: I’m curious — what features do you need in a PDF viewer, that’s available in Adobe Reader but not in the Linux PDF viewers (*e.g.* Okular or Evince)?

Comment: highlighting, comments etc that work on Win10 and Linux - when the pdf is shared between these platforms

Comment: animation doesn't work on okular and evince?

Answer (score 5):

There used to be an official Linux version of Acrobat Reader, but it was discontinued a few years ago. In fact, this is quite clearly stated on the very page you linked to:

[image: screenshot of the warning about this version of acrobat reader being old]

So, the page you mention simply points you to this very old version that might still be installable. The reason it isn't listed on Adobe's page is that it has been discontinued since 2013, almost 10 years ago.

As for flash, that is also mostly deprecated, and will be [discontinued this year](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html) for all operating systems.

Comment: oooff... i missed noticing the warning... I am going with Wine. Thx for pointing.

Answer (score 3):

1. The file exists because Adobe used to provide Linux versions of Adobe Reader. It’s not mentioned on the web site any more because it’s no longer supported (but they haven’t deleted the files from the FTP server). It shouldn’t be used, it has a large number of known vulnerabilities.
2. Yes, explore ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/ to see what’s available. (There’s probably nothing exciting for Linux.)